# BER formula for chirp spread spectrum BPSK modulation scheme

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, bpsk, spread-spectrum

May I know how to derive the [BER formula for chirp spread spectrum BPSK modulation scheme](https://unlab.tech/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/113900G.pdf#page=6) ?

[image: BER]

Comment: _Which_ of the three numbered formulas? The first (8) is a very standard result which can be found in _many_ texts on digital communications; some even list it for the more general case of two signals with unequal energies instead of two signals with equal energies as is the case for BPSK. The second (9) is wrong since it is missing normalization factors ($-1\leq\rho\leq 1$ is dead wrong!) while (10) follows from the first and the assertion that the chirp signals are antipodal (which is for a very special case of chirp and dead wrong when one signal is an up chirp  and the other a down chirp)

Comment: Another way to look at it is that (10) is the same result that you get for standard BPSK (i.e. antipodal signaling), taking spread spectrum out of the equation. Direct-sequence spread spectrum or chirp spread spectrum do not affect the bit error rate. Indeed they cannot affect the BER of the optimal receiver, due to the *principle of reversibility* (ref: *Principles of Communication Engineering* by Wozencraft and Jacobs). Application of the spreading waveform (sequence or chirp) is reversible, so an optimal receiver can just undo the operation first and obtain the same performance.

Comment: @JasonR Why BER metric could not reflect the superior performance of chirp spectrum BPSK with regards to the conventional BPSK ?

Comment: @DilipSarwate `−1 ≤ ρ ≤ 1` is dead wrong ?

Comment: Yes, if $\rho$ is defined by (9) in which the normalization is all wrong. With the correct normalization, the claim is correct.

Comment: @DilipSarwate What do you exactly mean by **normalization is all wrong** for expression (9) ?

Comment: If (9) is taken to be the _definition_ of $\rho$, then the claim that $-1 \leq \rho \leq 1$ is incorrect.  What _is_ true is that there is a positive number $M$ (which can be calculated but I won't bother doing so) such that $-M \leq \rho \leq M$. When $M > 1$, your book's definition of $\rho$ could lead to the quantity $1-\rho$ (which is in inside a square root sign in (8)) to be negative, and so $Q$ in (8) will have a complex argument.

Comment: @DilipSarwate if you look at [M-ary Orthogonal Chirp Modulation for Coherent and
Non-coherent Underwater Acoustic Communications](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.02950.pdf#page=7), this BER expression does not even contain *cross-correlation coefficient* as compared to (8) that you had seen in the original thread question above ?